# Is there any command that suppress redundant strings?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Using this command `find $FOAM_TUTORIALS -type f -name fvSchemes|xargs grep -rh div\(phi,U\)|sort`, I get:

```bsh
    div(div(phi,U)) Gauss linear;
    div(div(phi,U)) Gauss linear;
    div(div(phi,U)) Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss limitedLinear 0.2;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss limitedLinear 0.2;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss limitedLinear 0.2;
    div(phi,U)      bounded  Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)          bounded Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)          bounded Gauss linearUpwind grad;
    div(phi,U)       bounded Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)         bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)         bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)         bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)         bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)         bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)         bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)         bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)         bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)         bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
    div(phi,U)          bounded Gauss linearUpwind limited;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind limited;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind limited;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind limited;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind unlimited;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind unlimited;
    div(phi,U)              bounded Gauss linearUpwindV grad(U);
    div(phi,U)              bounded Gauss linearUpwindV grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwindV grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwindV grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwindV grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwindV grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwindV grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwindV grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwindV grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss localBlended linearUpwindV grad(U) linear;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss LUST grad(U);
    div(phi,U)                    bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)          bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)          bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)          bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)          bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss CoBlended
    div(phi,U)      Gauss cubic;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss cubic;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss DEShybrid
    div(phi,U)      Gauss DEShybrid
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinear 1;
    div(phi,U)          Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)          Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
//    div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)          Gauss linearUpwind limited;
    div(phi,U)          Gauss linearUpwind limited;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind limited;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwindV grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss LUST grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss LUST grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss LUST grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss LUST grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss LUST grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss LUST grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss LUST grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss LUST grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss LUST grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss LUST grad(U);
//    div(phi,U)      Gauss LUST grad(U);// linear;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss LUST unlimitedGrad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss skewCorrected linear;
    div(phi,U)          Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)          Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
//    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
//    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
//    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
//    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
//    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;//linearUpwind grad(U);
    div(phi,U)      Gauss vanLeerV;
```

I want the redundant lines to be shown only once, like this:

```bsh
div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss limitedLinear 0.2;
div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linear;
div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind grad;
div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind gradUConv;
div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind limited;
div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwind unlimited;
div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwindV grad(U);
div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss localBlended linearUpwindV grad(U) linear;
div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss LUST grad(U);
div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss upwind;
div(phi,U)      Gauss CoBlended 0.01 limitedLinearV 1 0.05 linearUpwind grad(U);
div(phi,U)      Gauss cubic;
div(phi,U)      Gauss DEShybrid linear linearUpwind grad(U) hmax 0.65 1 0.028 0 1 1;
div(phi,U)      Gauss DEShybrid linear linearUpwind grad(U) hmax 0.65 1 1 0 1 1;
div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinear 1;
"div\(phi.*,U.*\)" Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
div(phi,U)      Gauss limitedLinearV 1;
div(phi,U)      Gauss linear;
div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind grad(U);
div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwind limited;
div(phi,U)      Gauss linearUpwindV grad(U);
div(phi,U)      Gauss LUST grad(U);
div(phi,U)      Gauss LUST unlimitedGrad(U);
div(phi,U)      Gauss skewCorrected linear;
"div\(phi.*,U.*\)" Gauss upwind;
div(phi,U)      Gauss upwind;
div(phi,U)      Gauss vanLeerV;
```

Comment: Can you add `sort -iu` to the end of the pipeline?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Great; but some same lines that are different only regarding delimiters are still double-counted, e.g. `div(phi,U)          bounded Gauss linear;` and `div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linear;` are not considered unique. Is there any workaround for this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that your input is in a file named `inputfile.txt`.

You can run:
`sed -e 's/ \+/ /g' inputfile.txt | grep -v "\/\/" | sort -u`

Explanation:

- `sed -e 's/ \+/ /g' inputfile.txt` replaces multiple occurrences of blank to one single blank. In this way it's more simple to perform the final sorting/comparison
- `grep -v "\/\/"` removes commented lines
- eventually `sort -u` removes duplicated lines.

This solution works well if you don't care about replacing multiple blank spaces with a single one.

These commands may be merged in your original command in this way:

`find $FOAM_TUTORIALS -type f -name fvSchemes | xargs grep -rh div\(phi,U\) | sed -e 's/ \+/ /g' | grep -v "\/\/" | sort -u`